# Default monospace font with text.usetex in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts, latex

I need to use `rc('text', usetex=True)` in one of my plots, and I noticed that it changes the fonts that are used in the figure.

Before:

```
from matplotlib import rc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rc('font', **{'family': 'monospace', 'monospace': 'Deja Vu Sans Mono', 'size': 25})
rc('text', usetex=False)

plt.clf()
x = [0,1,2]
y = [1,1,1]
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.ylabel(r"This is $y=1$", size=25)
plt.xlabel(r"This is x", size=25)
plt.show()
```

[image]
After:

```
...
rc('text', usetex=True)
...
```

[image]

I tried working with the `'mathtext.*'` rc properties but I could find the settings that can align these two outputs. Is there a catch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Text rendering with LaTeX doc](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/usetex.html), *"only a small number of font families are supported"*. 
 I'll let you check the available font families but for the `monospace` family, only Computer Modern Typewriter and  Courier are supported.